# Design a Moore automaton for this datapath

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

I'm having some trouble.

The datapath of a multicycle CPU takes 5 clocks (t0,1,2,3,4) to execute an instruction. Assume that an operand of the ALU is loaded in R4 at t1 and the other one in R5 at t2.
Design a Moore automaton which drives CE4(clock enable R4) and CE5 (clock enable R5).
In addition trace the temporal evolution of CE4 and CE5 and complete the bubble diagram.

I suppose "designing the Moore automaton" means to complete the bubble diagram.
Anyone who can put me on the good track or providing some lecture where I get to learn more about this topic would be really appreciated.

I can't really understand if what I am supposed to do is something like what I tried: 
[image: What I tried]

A clean version of the exercise looks like this:

[image: Clean Exercise]

Comment: Are you sure you presented the whole assignment? If that's all, the assignment is beyond nonsensical and your teacher should probably find a profession that doesn't involve teaching.

Comment: Yes, the second half of the exercise asks about the Qs functions and Output functions.
There are other examples such as 
"The datapath of a CPU with a multicycle architecture takes 5 clock hits (t0,t1,t2,t3,t4) to complete an operation. Assuming the ALU should sum the value in R4 loaded in t1 and R5 loaded in t3.
Same picture, same assignment (bubble diagram for Moore + functions).
I emailed him hoping for an answer.
Thanks for your answer tho!